# WCF dataset compression

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, dataset, compression

I have a wcf client which receives a dataset from a wcf service. It is over LAN and uses NetTcpBinding. I am using the default binary encoding. The size of the dataset can be huge depending on the type of call (these types of calls maybe 5% of the total calls). Also in future the service might be available through http binding.

As far as I know binary encoding provides the best compression of all the available encoders. Is there a way to get better compression on the dataset before sending it to the client?

Comment: its a very bad idea to return data set

Comment: @Ostap: Agreed. Unfortunately that is what i have to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary vs. HTTP binding does not represent compression. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751458.aspx) in MSDN provides a thorough discussion how to implement a custom message encoder that involves compression of the data stream.

Comment: Thanks. I will be going through the article.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at protobuf-net(r356). There is also a blog post from Marc Gravell, a great user here on StackOverflow: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2010/10/datatable-life-in-old-beast.html